# Concept of labels in SharpSvn

Tags: svn, tfs, sharpsvn

Do we have the concept of labels(similar to VersioncontrolLabel in Microsoft TFS) in SharpSvn?
I am trying to use the SvnClient.SetRevisionProperty Method to set the label for the latest version but not sure if there is any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion does not work the same way as TFS, and does not have anything built in that is analogous to what I've gleaned about TFS labels.

The closest corresponding action in SVN would be to create a tag, which is just a copy which follows a naming/directory location convention. But to Subversion internally, it's just a copy.